# image not insert in mysql using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, image, codeigniter, image-uploading

I am trying to insert images in mysql database with other data but its shows error.
its shows the $msg of not saved & repeat data of view file maybe due to $error which i set.
PS: I set 'image' datatype varchar in database.
here is my view file:

```
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image" id="exampleInputFile" >
```

this is my controller:

```
 public function save()
{
  $this->load->model('Partner_model');
 $feature = $this->input->post('feature');

  $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/files';
           $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
           $config['max_size']             = 100;
           $config['max_width']            = 1024;
           $config['max_height']           = 768;
           $this->load->library('upload', $config);
           if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
{
       $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
       $this->load->view('partner_profile', $error);
}
else
{


  $user_data= array(

   'pname' => $this->input->post('pname'),
   'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
   'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
   'about' => $this->input->post('about'),
   'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
   'code' => $this->input->post('code'),
   'state'=>$this->input->post('state'),
//  'image'=>$this->upload->do_upload('image')
  'feature'=>implode(",",$feature),
   'image' => $this->upload->data()

    );  
   }

    if($this->Partner_model->save($user_data))
   {
       $msg = "save sucesss" ;
   }
   else
   {
       $msg = "not save";
   }

   $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);
   $this->load->view('partner_profile');
 }
}
```

& this is my model:

```
    public function save($data)
  {

   return $this->db->insert('property', $data);

  }
```

Comment: "its shows error. its shows the $msg of not saved & repeat data of view file maybe due to $error which i set." don't know what this means. can you share the exact error output you are receiving?

Comment: Are you using form_open_multipart() or does your form have a "multipart" attribute? That will be needed to work with uploads.

Comment: $this->upload->data() returns array and you are passing it simply to save in db. The line 'image' => $this->upload->data() should be 'image' => $this->upload->data()['file_name']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form must have the multipart attribute in HTML file like below :

If you're using form helper, then it should be

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('/save');?>
```

Else your form should have the enctype attribute like below

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then the uploaded data result **$this->upload->data()** will come in array. So you can't store your array in mysql column. So you need to get the filename from $this->upload->data() and store it in a variable like below.

Your Controller should be

```
public function save(){
 $this->load->model('Partner_model');
 $feature = $this->input->post('feature');

 $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/files';
 $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
 $config['max_size']             = 100;
 $config['max_width']            = 1024;
 $config['max_height']           = 768;
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
 if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')){
   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
   $this->load->view('partner_profile', $error);
 }else{
  $imageArray = $this->upload->data();
  $image =  $imageArray['file_name'];
  $user_data= array(
   'pname' => $this->input->post('pname'),
   'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
   'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
   'about' => $this->input->post('about'),
   'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
   'code' => $this->input->post('code'),
   'state'=>$this->input->post('state'),
   'feature'=>implode(",",$feature),
   'image' => $image
  );  
 }
 if($this->Partner_model->save($user_data)) {
   $msg = "save sucesss" ;
 }else {
   $msg = "not save";
 }
 $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);
 $this->load->view('partner_profile');
}
```